# How to avoid shuffle in SortMerge Join on partitioned column?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We got two datasets thats been persisted as follows:

Dataset A:

```
datasetA.repartition(5, datasetA.col("region")) 
                .write().mode(saveMode) 
                .format("parquet") 
                .partitionBy("region") 
                .bucketBy(5,"studentId") 
                .sortBy("studentId") 
                .option("path", parquetFilesDirectory) 
                .saveAsTable( database.tableA));
```

Dataset B:

```
datasetB.repartition(5, datasetB.col("region")) 
                .write().mode(saveMode) 
                .format("parquet") 
                .partitionBy("region") 
                .bucketBy(5,"studentId") 
                .sortBy("studentId") 
                .option("path", parquetFilesDirectory) 
                .saveAsTable( database.tableB));
```

Join on region and studentId causes data shuffle.  Below is the join query :

```
spark.sql("Select count(*)  from  database.tableA a, database.tableB b where a.studentId = b.studentId and a.region = b.region").show()
```

What could be the reason for the shuffle when we include the partition key 
and how can we mitigate it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mitigate Shuffling using pre-sort and group tables

Comment: Can you please add some examples or more explanation to your answer to make it useful? Right now, it doesn't provide any guidance, just some key-words

Comment: @Alpesh: PartitionKeys cannot be a part of bucketing or sorting columns.